# Adding a value to an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Hey all i just want to make sure i am adding the value correctly to my array varable:

```
$post_values = array(
"x_first_name"      => $_POST['first_name'],
"x_last_name"       => $_POST['last_name']
);
```

If anyone could confirm that its the way it needs to be then please do :o)

David

Comment: You can check this yourself here: [http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Looks okay to me, but like @tbraun89 said. Double check it with the link he provided.

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey, Eric Wutchin: Thanks! :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That works, but these also work:

```
$post_values = array();
$post_values['x_first_name'] = $_POST['first_name'];

$post_values = array();
array_push($post_values, $_POST['first_name'];
// but now you don't have the desired index, just numeric indexes
```

You might also first want to check whether the post value exists:

```
if (isset($_POST['first_name']) {
    $post_values['x_first_name'] = $_POST['first_name'];
}
```

Comment: tbraun89's tip is also good, the php.net website has a lot of examples.

Comment: It would be if it showed an example of what i was looking for **"XXXX" => $POST['XXXX'],**

Answer (score -1):

you could also do

```
$post_values = array();
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
   $post_values['x_' . $k] = $v;
}
```

and please do validate POST inputs!

```
$post_values['x_' . htmlentities($k, ENT_QUOTES)] = htmlentities($v, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: Using `htmlentities` here is wrong. You should not use it to validate data (the function does not even validate anything!), but you have to use it to escape data in the correct context. htmlentities does not help anything when working with a database, json, csv, links, etc.

Comment: "Validate" is maybe a wrong term but htmlentities prevents malicious code from being injected. Which, to my knowledge, is never wrong to try and prevent

Comment: No, it only prevents malicious code from being injected into html documents. Variables themselves are not in html context until echoed. You don't get any benefit from it when you use the variable in another context (csv, json, databases …)